# How to show $\text{Im } i=\text{ker }\pi$ for sequece $0\xrightarrow{}X'\xrightarrow{i}X\xrightarrow{\pi}X/X'\xrightarrow{}0?$

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence

The following is taken from "Linear Algebra and Geometry" by Leung.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercuse}$  Show that for each subspace $X'$ of a linear space $X,$ the sequence

$$0\xrightarrow{}X'\xrightarrow{i}X\xrightarrow{\pi}X/X'\xrightarrow{}0$$

where $i$ is the inclusion mapping and $\pi$ the natural surjection, is exact.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

For the above exercise, let's relabel the above sequence as: $0\xrightarrow{f_1}X'\xrightarrow{i}X\xrightarrow{\pi}X/X'\xrightarrow{f_2}0.$  We know that   $\text{Im }f_1=\text{ker }i=f_i(0)=0,$ and so $\text{Im} f_1=X'.$  We also have $\text{Im } \pi=\pi(X)=X/X'=\text{ker }f_2.$ Since $i$ is injective and being a linear transformation means that $\text{ker } i=0$ and $\text{Im } i=i(X')=X.$ But how do I show that $\text{Im } i=\text{ker }\pi?$

Thank you in advance

Comment: $\text{Image}(i)=\ker \pi$ since the sequence is exact. That’s what it means: the image of the arrow before equals the kernel of the one after.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I thought at each of the vector subspace, I have to show $\text{Im 
 }f_{i+1}=\text{ker }f_i,$  in order to show that the entire sequence of mapping is exact.  Meaning, $\text{Im }f_{1}=\text{ker }i,$ $\text{Im }i=\text{ker }\pi,$ and $\text{Im }\pi=\text{ker }f_2.$  I don't know how to show $\text{Im }i=\text{ker }\pi,$

Comment: oh my bad, I mixed this up with your other question where exactness was the hypothesis. In the case where $X’$ is actually a subspace of $X$, simply note that the image of $X’$ is equal to $X’$ by definition of what the canonical injection $i$ means. Also, $X’$ is the kernel of the quotient map $\pi:X\to X/X’$, again since that’s essentially how the quotient space (and map) are defined (to be explicit, $[v]\in X/X’$ equals $0$ iff $v\sim 0$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation, and this by definition is such that $v-0\in X’$, i.e $v\in X’$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo ah kk.  Thank you. I forgot that little fact about equivalence business..  By the way, this question, if we change the context of the subspaces/spaves to either groups/modules.  The reasonsing would be alsmost similar?